# Stripe - Is it safe to expose the charge id to the user?

Tags: stripe-payments

I want to know if it is safe to expose the charge ID e.g. ch_abc123. I want to know this so I have a way to issue refunds to a customer securely.

I was thinking of asking the customer for their details e.g. email, date of purchase but then I thought that there would not be a way to ensure the identity of the person requesting a refund.

Ideally, I would show the customer the charge ID so they can provide it when asking for a refund.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The charge ID itself is a unique ID that you can't do anything interesting with on its own, except by using your Stripe secret key, which you should protect.

But precisely because it is a simple unique ID that is not considered sensitive on its own, you should not rely it on as a form of authentication — the customer might share it or have it stolen. Or they could lose it and still want to get a refund.

I would suggest instead that you store the charge ID on your backend server along with any other order metadata that you have, and provide the option to request a refund only after the customer has authenticated to your system.